# GitLab deploy FTP via CI microsoft/dotnet?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, gitlab, gitlab-ci, asp.net-core-2.1

I'm trying to implement an FTP deploy through the CI of GitLab, using microsoft/dotnet docker image.
I searched everywhere, but I could not find a way to do it.

I tried this:
https://forum.gitlab.com/t/deploy-via-ftp-via-ci/2631

```
apt-get install lftp
lftp -e "mirror -R $LOCAL_DIR $REMOTE_DIR" -u $USERNAME,$PASSWORD $HOST
```

But I got this error:
[image: gitlab console error]

Does anyone know any way to do this?

Here is my .gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
image: microsoft/dotnet:latest

stages:
  - build
  - test
  - deploy

variables:
  project: "aspnetcore.devops.example.api"
  publishdir: "bin\\release\\netcoreapp2.1\\publish\\"
  remotedir: "dotnetcoretest"
  ftphost: "myhost"
  ftpusername: "myuser"
  ftppassword: "mypass"

before_script:
  - "dotnet restore"

build:
  stage: build
  variables:
    build_path: "src/$project"
  script:
    - "cd $build_path"
    - "dotnet build"

test:
  stage: test
  variables:
    test_path: "src/$project.tests"
  script:
    - "cd $test_path"
    - "dotnet test"

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  variables:
    deploy_path: "src/$project"
  script:
    - "cd $deploy_path"
    - "dotnet publish -c release"
    - "apt-get install lftp"
    - "lftp -e \"mirror -R $publishdir $remotedir\" -u $ftpusername,$ftppassword $ftphost"
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try to run `apt-get update` before `apt-get install lftp`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way that worked, more or less like @Sascha Frinken said:

I changed:

```
- "apt-get install lftp"
```

To:

```
- apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y -qq lftp
```